# how to check if a subgroup is maximal?

Tags: group-theory, maximal-subgroup

Is there any general strategy to check whether a subgroup is maximal or not ? For example, in case of rings, we know that an ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is maximal if and only if $R/I$ is a field. Is there something like this for groups ?

Comment: Well, the "correct" analogue of ideals for groups are normal subgroups, which are maximal precisely when they are of prime index (and maximal among normal subgroups when the quotient is simple).

Answer (score 1):

There is an equivalent condition, that a subgroup $H$ of index $n>1$ in a group $G$ is maximal if and only if the image of the permutation action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$ in $G$ is a primitive subgroup of $S_n$. This test is often used in computer calculations, because there are fast tests for primitivity.